# iPhone 4 iOS 7 with no iCloud backup. Is there way to access data?

Tags: ios, iphone, recovery

I recently lost my iPhone. I have no SIM and no backups (either local, or in iCloud).

Is there a way to recover the lost data? For example, the call history, messages, contacts etc.

Answer (score 2):

Without any kind of backup there is no way to get the data unless you find the iPhone.

If you remember your **Apple ID** and password, you can login to [appleid.apple.com](https://appleid.apple.com) and set the device as lost.  This should keep a thief or anyone who finds the phone from accessing your personal data.  Hopefully you have the iPhone set with a passcode to unlock.

From [Apple Support using Lost Mode](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH19299?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US):

> If you can’t find your iOS device, Apple Watch, or Mac, use Lost Mode right away to lock it and keep track of its location. For more information, or if you can’t use Lost Mode because Find My iPhone wasn’t set up on your lost device, see the Apple Support article [If your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch is lost or stolen.](https://support.apple.com/HT201472)

Comment: +1 for adding the info about logging into appleid.apple.com. That's a good suggestion in this situation! :)

Answer (score 1):

**The short answer is no**, assuming you have *never* used iCloud or made local backups.

Basically, if you:

- don't use iCloud then the data isn't going to be synced across to other devices (such as an iPad or Mac) and therefore you won't be able to retrieve data such as contacts from other devices.
- have no local backup, then there's nothing from which you can restore the data from.

However, if you've made backups in the past, either with iCloud or via iTunes, then you *may* have the ability to retrieve some data (albeit dated).

Comment: +1 We must have been typing at the same time! ;). Nice answer

Answer (score 1):

This question mentions no backup is available; however there’s still a chance the OP was using an iCloud account. If that is the case, then the following is already in iCloud even without a backup, and can be recovered simply by connecting a new iPhone to your iCloud account:

- Your contacts
- Your email
- Your notes
- Your calendar appointments
- Your reminders
- Your voice memos
- iBooks you had saved in iCloud
- Your favorite locations in Maps
- Your Safari bookmarks and open tabs
- Music and movies you purchased directly from iTunes
- The rest of your music, *if you subscribed to iTunes Match or MUSIC*
- Your photos, *if you subscribed to iCloud Photo Library*

In fact you could login to [iCloud.com](https://www.icloud.com/) and see that data on the web already.

Note that many of these bullet points would also apply if you used some other service that stores all its data in the cloud, eg. Gmail or Outlook.

What you will NOT be able to recover:

- Your messages
- Your call history
- Your voicemail
- Your Health and WATCH data
- Your music, if you did *not* subscribe to iTunes Match or MUSIC
- Your photos, if you did *not* subscribe to iCloud Photo Library

Starting with iOS 11, messages will also be stored in iCloud, so you will not need to backup your iPhone to keep a history of your messages.

I know this doesn’t help you here; however if you’ve got another Apple device connected to your iCloud account with **Text Forwarding** enabled, activating **iCloud Messages** once it becomes available will push all those conversations from that device back onto your new iPhone.